# MassTransit pulling messages from external system

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

How can MassTransit pull messages from a RabbitMQ when the messages were sent from a different message sending source(RabbitMQ Client in this case)?

The messages share the same C# message contract and serialized as json.

The current error I receive is masstransit parsing error...

Answer (score 3):

MassTransit uses a number of conventions and there are additional details you that would probably need to add to the payload if publishing from a non-MassTransit publisher.  If you're getting a parsing error you are probably missing the messageType information below.

**Payload:**

```
{
  "destinationAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/<exchange>",
  "headers": {},
  "message": {
    "property": "value"
  },
  "messageType": [    
    "urn:message:<TYPE>",
    "urn:message:<PARENT_TYPE>"
  ],
  "sourceAddress": "rabbitmq://localhost/queue"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code snippet or the exception details?

Comment: Adding the **messageType** was one issue.  I also figured out I had to add a Header with content type that looks like: {"Content-Type", "application/vnd.masstransit+json"}.  To create a message from outside of MT, the three basic things it needs to be processed successfully are Message, MessageType, and Content-Type.  Now the issue is changing the content-type string to just be "application/json".  After looking at the MT code, looks like I'll need a custom serializer??

Comment: You'll need to serialize the messages in an envelope that matches the style of the ```JsonMessageSerializer``` in MT. The envelope must include a few values as shown above, and the algorithm for the message type is in the ```MessageUrn``` class.